# Calculate distance between two latitudes/longitudes in MapKit / CoreLocation

Tags: core-location

Im looking to use the `getDistanceFrom` method in CoreLocation to determine distance between two points, but i get errors when trying to use CoreLocation...

Im using 3.1.2. I have tried this, but returns an error:

```
CLLocation *userLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:appDelegate.mapView2.userLocation.coordinate];
CLLocation *poiLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: [aPOI.latitude doubleValue] longitude: [aPOI.longitude doubleValue]];

double dist = [userLoc getDistanceFrom:poiLoc] / 1000;

NSLog(@"%d",dist);
```

error given:

```
".objc_class_name_CLLocation", referenced from:
literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocation in POIDetailViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

am i missing something? i have imported `CoreLocation`...

Is this method deprecated in 3.1.2?

Thanks

Comment: so ok, i fixed the error, but now am getting a huge number (1862709713) returned for `dist`? Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the framework search directories from the project.pbxproject file inside the Xcode project bundle

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a CoreLocation framework to the project.